# Detecting trend divergence between two time-series datasets

Tags: time-series

Is there a relatively simple to implement method out there for detecting the early stages of divergence between two time series ?  To take a simple example from the financial area, a common one is detecting the start of divergence between asset price and an associated "indicator" or "oscillator" chart in order to identify the begginings of a trend reversal.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a percentage difference between the two variables then evaluate with a plot like a simple time series or cusum chart ([CUSUM Control Charts](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section3/pmc323.htm)) should give you what you are after.

Comment: Also, thanks @Nikolas Rieble for the fixed link description.